# How can I access the application using selenium webdriver that works through VPN?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, vpn

For example, I have an application "www.test.com", to access this site I have installed browsec VPN in firefox then I can see the application content - accessing the site without vpn I get an error of "Your IP Address has been blocked..bla bla" Now I want to test some UI of that site through Selenium Webdriver, but when I try to access the site via selenium webdriver I get same error of IP blocked since the vpn is already installed on firefox, but webdriver doesn't bother the VPN - that's my question how can I access the such applications through Selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 6):

You have to load the extension using firefox profiles in WebDriver. The path to extension file is usually here `C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ew0u966b.default-1507268891903\extensions`

```
WebDriver driver = null;

FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
File addonpath = new File("path of addon/extension (.xpi file)");
firefoxProfile.addExtension(addonpath);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

driver.get("http://www.helloselenium.com");

driver.quit();
```

http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-add-addon-to-firefox-instance-of.html

For chrome see below link

http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/08/24/adding-add-on-in-firefox-and-chrome-using-webdriver/

***To start the extension, the following should work.***

Every extension will have a unique id which can be used to open the extension in the browser. When you install browsec plugin, you will get a url like this indicating the id. `moz-extension://f1b30486-cd88-4319-bbb5-d5e387103414/congratulations.html` I am not sure about how to obtain this id in any other way or whether it will be same for different installations. I have asked a question in SO for the same -
 [Get add-on id of extensions in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056506/get-add-on-id-of-extensions-in-firefox)

Replacing `congratulations.html` with `popup.html` should open the extension in the browser. You can then treat this like a normal webpage and automate it using selenium WebDriver. After you start the extension in this way, you can then load the url of the application under test and continue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sighil, I can see the VPN on firefox instance opening through the script but the VPN is disabled - How can I enable it using selenium webdriver?