# Get add-on id of extensions in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to open extensions in browser tab as a normal html page so that I can automate it using selenium WebDriver. In firefox this can be done using link like this - `moz-extension://f1b30486-cd88-4319-bbb5-d5e387103414/popup.html`.

[image]

> But the problem is that I am not finding a way in Firefox by which I can locate the id for all extensions**. The id used above is obtained when the extension is installed and a page with url `moz-extension://f1b30486-cd88-4319-bbb5-d5e387103414/congratulations.html` is loaded like a welcome page.

**Is there any way in Firefox to get the add-on id or get urls like above for all extensions.**

Comment: Can you access about:debugging?

Comment: Yes I can ... Did not find it there .

Comment: Really? Did you reinstall the extension maybe? The UUID after moz-extension:// should match one of the extensions "Internal UUID" entries.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Open `about:memory`. Click "measure" in **Show memory reports**. In the **Main Process** section, scroll down to **Other Measurements**. There you will find the installed (active) extensions with their names and their ids displayed as *baseURL=moz-extension://[**random-ids**]*.

This method works for both Firefox and Firefox for Android. Note that only enabled extensions are shown.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there ... now ?

Comment: @TadLewis You have to click the "Measure" button first, then the list shows up containing "Other Measurements" and the extensions.

Answer (score 22):

I tried the other two and they both worked but I really had to search to find which extension was which

I found that using `about:debugging` was very clear as to which extension was which I̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶h̶a̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶ ̶`̶T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶F̶i̶r̶e̶f̶o̶x̶`̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶a̶d̶e̶d̶

Just go to `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`and it will give you the following

- Extension Picture next to Extension Name
- Extension ID
- Internal UUID
- Manifest URL

Comment: Or just `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`

Comment: Happy to save the clicks, IMO this is definitely the preferred answer, thanks for sharing your finding.

Answer (score 8):

Just open `about:config` and then look at this: `extensions.webextensions.uuids`

Comment: this the better answer