# Setup VPN through python script for web crawling

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy, vpn

I have been using selenium to do some web scraping and I'm in need for changing my ip. After having done some reserach into this I have discovered that it is fairly easy to setup and use a proxy. However, I am already paying for a VPN and therefore I would like to use it for this application as well. The free proxy lists that I have found have been way to slow to be useful for me.

I did some googling and found vpnc and other libraries but I couldn't get it to work all the way. I'm fairly new to web scraping and python so therefore I would appreciate if someone could help me on my level of knowledge.

Is it possible to do this or am I trying to achieve something that is way to difficult for an amateur like me? I'm trying to set this up on MacOS as well as Windows 7.

Comment: Check out this link: <https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/5cs529/setting_up_selenium_vpn_with_python_would_really/> also here are few links that if first didnt help. ( but I think it should work as a guy on reddit said )

<https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-run-a-Selenium-test-browser-on-VPN> <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996321/how-can-i-access-the-application-using-selenium-webdriver-that-works-through-vpn?noredirect=1&lq=1>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't get anywhere with those links. It is to abstract still. Maybe I am in over my head. Also I'm somewhat hesitant to start a VPN on the OS level since that affects all scripts and everything on my computer. Is there anyway through a network manager or something to limit the VPN connection to a single script?

Comment: Ngrok seemed promising but it is also way above my knowledge. I barley know what I'm reading as I'm trying to understand it.