# How to use VPN in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I am trying an application in the Chrome browser using Selenium.

**My problem:** I decided to use a VPN because I can't access my 'IP'.
I need to access IP's using VPN.

Comment: Please help yourself - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996321/how-can-i-access-the-application-using-selenium-webdriver-that-works-through-vpn